# Show that ${1, x, x^2, x^3, ...}$ is linearly independent.

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra

$Q$: Show that the non-negative powers of $x$ ($1, x, x^2, x^3,$ etc.) are linearly independent in $C^0[0,1]$ (The continuous real-valued functions on $[0,1]$) and give an example of a continuous function in $C^0[0,1]$ that is not spanned by this list.

---

I know one way you can prove this is by showing that if this list was linearly dependent you would end up with a polynomial with infinite roots, so it must be the constant zero polynomial, and thus this list is linearly independent.

But I'm looking for a solution using ideas from Calculus. I believe the approach is to keep taking derivatives and showing that the constants must be zero, but I'm having a hard time formalizing this into a proof for this infinite list.

Comment: How do you define an indeterminate and its powers? This gives you the answer.

Comment: Does "Calculus" encompass Rolle's Theorem?

Comment: @AnginaSeng my prof seemed to imply the answer involved taking the derivative.

Comment: What do you mean by $C_0([0,1])$?

Comment: @Wuestenfux I'm not quite sure what you mean by that. Could you elaborate a bit?

Comment: @uniquesolution the continuous real-valued functions on [0,1]. I've updated the question to include this.

Comment: The standard notation is $C[0,1]$. The notation $C_0(X)$ is reserved for continuous functions on $X$ "vanishing at infinity"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose not, then there exists some
$$\sum_{i=0}^n a_ix^i = 0$$
(Recall that linear independence only requires taking finite sum) RHS we have the zero function. Now taking derivative $j$ times we have the constant term of the LHS to be $j!a_j$. Now evaluate at $x=0$ one observes that $j!a_j = 0$  in particular, $a_j = 0$. Since $j$ was arbitrary, it follows that all $a_j$ are zero.

So now finally, consider the exponential function $e^x$. Clearly continuous but does not lie in the span of monomials of power of $x$ since those can only form all polynomials.

Comment: I see the approach your taking. Would you be able to explicitly show what happens to the rest of the terms where i > j?

Comment: You can let $j$ run from $0,..,n$ and it would show you all the constants are equal to zero. We don't really care about the terms larger than $j$ for now.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**:

Look at the value of the $n$-th derivative of a polynomial at $x=0$.

Comment: In particular, this also addresses the final part, of verifying some continuous functions aren't in the span.

Comment: Could you please shed some light on the effect of having k-th derivative of a polynomial equal zero on the original polynomial zeros? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You must show that for any $c_0, c_1, \cdots, c_n \in \mathbb{R}$, if $c_0 + c_1 x + \cdots + c_n x^n = 0$, then $c_0=c_1=\cdots=c_n=0$, i.e, $f(x) = c_0 + c_1x + \cdots + c_n x^n$ is zero function. Think about the number of zeros of polynomial in terms of degree.

Comment: The OP has explicitly stated that they know of this solution, but want an alternative solution using ideas from calculus.